# DB2 Database Export in Oracle SQL Developer gives an empty connection list

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to backup my DB so I use Tools --> Database Export.
However, when I want to choose my connection I got no connection in drop down list.

Just to mention that I can see my connection list in "Connections" tab and also all connections in "C:\Users{MyUser}\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system3.0.04.34\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.31\connections.xml" file

Same behavior happens also in "Database Copy", "database Diff" and in "Monitor SQL"

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That version is so old...it's like from 2010. Also, if you want a backup of your database you should use rman or data Pump

Comment: Also that feature is for Oracle only...if you're trying to use it for MySQL, SQL server, db2...that's why they're not showing up

Comment: Yes, It's db2.. I will try rman or data Pump

Comment: if it's DB2, you need to use your DB2 interfaces to get a good backup - that would not be SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

The Database Export feature is built for Oracle Databases only. That's why you aren't seeing your DB2 connections in the Export, Copy, or DIFF wizards in ORACLE SQL Developer (keyword, Oracle).

If you want to backup your IBM DB2 database, you need to use the tools that IBM gives you for managing DB2.